# What discs do I need to install?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Do I have to install the first disc to grand theft auto five or can I just play the second disc. What do I need to do.

Comment: Please write descriptive titles for your questions.

Comment: @kotekzot No. This title is the best.

Comment: @SaintWacko it is certainly the best at attracting downvotes and communicating that the asker hasn't put any effort into getting a good answer, I'll give you that.

Comment: @Fluttershy I'd say they're different enough. That one's about whether it's better to install the second disk as well. This one's about whether installing the first disk is required.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to install the first disk. Without installing the first disk the game will not run. The second disk should be read from the drive, however.